# Removing hashtags, usernames and URLs from tweet using Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Is there an easy way to remove hashtags, usernames and URLs mentioned in a tweet using twitter4j?
I know that using getHashtagEntities(), getUserMentionEntities() and getURLEntities() I can retrieve those entities and their position in the string but how would I use them to "clean up" tweets?

I was thinking of using the replaceAll(entity, "") method to replace all those entities in the tweet with "" but that wouldn't always give correct results (.e.g it would remove #ht from the " _#ht " tweet even though it shouldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a lookbehind `"(?<!\w)"` with the `replaceAll()` method for each entity and I guess this solved my problem. However I was told that regex and the `replaceAll()` method can be quite slow so if anyone has any other suggestions I'd be happy to read them.

Comment: What class implements this removeAll?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write replaceAll(). I was working with String objects.